# Workaround for inlineshape.LinkFormat.Update

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am writing a Word 2007 document with a lot of images that are sure to change before the document is delivered. Therefore, I am inserting them in the document as links to PNG files. My problem is that if I select the image and execute:

```
Selection.InlineShapes(1).LinkFormat.Update
MsgBox Selection.InlineShapes(1).LinkFormat is Nothing
```

the message box displays "True". That is, the Update method broke the link.

I have tried using Selection.InlineShapes(1).Delete, followed by Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture. This updates the image, but now I need to crop the image and that introduces its own set of problems. Before trying to deal with the cropping issues, I'm hoping that someone has a better way of updating the linked file.

BTW, closing the document and reopening it updates the image nicely as long as the filename has not changed. The point of the macro is to cope with filename changes, if necessary.

Comment: which office version you use?